# In the Wizard of Oz, the scarecrow sings, "If I only had a brain." Doesn't he really mean, "If only I had a brain"?

Tags: word-order

In the Wizard of Oz, the scarecrow sings, "If I only had a brain." Doesn't he really mean, "If only I had a brain"?

I think the sentence the scarecrow sings actually asks what it would be like if he had only one thing, a brain. That, however, is not what he wants to ask.

The reason I ask is that I am playing off this song in a post I am writing on dualism. I was going to title it, "If Only Souls Had a Brain". But when I listened to the song again, I would need to rewrite it as, "If Souls Only Had a Brain" to do a proper play on the scarecrow's words. I think "If Souls Only Had a Brain" is so poorly written, I will just modify what the scarecrow says, and title my post "If Only Souls Had a Brain".

Maybe the scarecrow would have used better grammar, if only he had a brain!

Comment: Even if the grammar is bad it only adds to the truth of the situation. He *Doesn't* have a brain. If he did he would be saying it betterer. Wouldn't he.

Comment: Lyrics, being a form of art, are exempt from normal strictures concerning word order and placement.

Comment: I don't think the question has been fully dealt with by the previous question and its answers.

Comment: 'If only' is a fixed phrase, and that is the default sense here, not [If] [only {I}]. From [CD](): << If only  [Grammar > Verbs > Conditionals and wishes > _If only_ 
[from English Grammar Today]: 
We use _if only_ to express a strong wish that things could be different. It means the same as _I wish_ but is stronger. We use it to talk about past, present and future unreal conditions.  _If only he knew the truth._ (he doesn’t know the truth, but he wishes he did)  >> The ordering is sometimes switched (_If he only knew the truth._) but this is not mandatory and more formal....

Comment: And again, the alternative reading ('If he only _knew_ the truth ... even that would be something; he doesn't have to fully espouse it at this time.') is again not the default.

Comment: Sorry; the [Cambridge Dictionary link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/if-only). They class the fixed phrase as an idiom, and they're probably right (unusual usage of 'only', after complementiser if analysing word for word).

Answer (score 1):

Dorothy asks the Scarecrow, who wants a brain, "What would you do with a brain if you had one?". And the Scarecrow's song "If I Only Had a Brain" is in response to the question. So the song easily could have been "If I Had a Brain" (without "Only"), but it included "Only" to emphasize how much he wanted a brain.

In this context, both *If I only had a brain* and *If only I had a brain* work with little difference in meaning.

It's worth noting, though, that it's a 1939 movie. According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If%20only%20I%20had%20a%2BIf%20only%20I%20had%20an%2CIf%20I%20only%20had%20a%2BIf%20I%20only%20had%20an&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), "If I only had a/an" was more productive than "If only I had a/an" until around 1949, after which point the latter became more productive than the former.

Answer (score 1):

The use of "only", in this context, is not intended to separate those who have brains from those who don't.  Rather, "if only" is expressing a wish.

For instance, if I were wanting to bake some bread and I did not have any yeast for leavening, I might say "If only I had some yeast".  This does not imply that I want to be the only person in my community to possess yeast, but rather it means that I wish I had some yeast.

Answer (score -2):

On the contrary,

> If only I had a brain

means if *I* had a brain, and no one else did, because "only" modifies "I".  "If Only Souls Had a Brain" means that nothing else has a brain.

> if I only had a brain

means that if I *had a brain* and nothing more (in context, nothing more in addition to what he already has).

Comment: It's not ambiguous because context is an intrinsic part of language. It's absurd to assume that only the scarecrow has a brain, so there's essentially no room for misunderstanding. "If I only had a brain," is an ideal formulation because it fits the rhythm of the song and because, as is the case with the above suggestion, the meaning is not ambiguous; it's absurd to assume that the scarecrow is singing about a condition in which he has a brain and, uh... nothing else.

Answer (score -2):

"If I only had a brain" is not bad grammar, but if you want to adjust it for the sake of your title, feel free to do so.